# How to replace color in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, png

I would like to replace black color in transparent PNG for bluish color from my other image.

Bluish color sampled:

[image]

So, desired color is `#00528f`.

Unfortunately, it does not work as I would expect in `Change Color` dialog:

[image]

Why isn't it obey direct order of a human and how to make it work as expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you’d like to accurately apply a flat colour to a PNG with transparency, while maintaining the transparency, there’s many ways Photoshop can do it.

Here’s probably the easiest method:

- Open the PNG.
- Choose Layer → Layer Style → Color Overlay
- Choose a colour (using normal blending mode and 100% opacity).
- You’re done!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I hope this might help. In <kbd>Image...Adjustments</kbd>/<kbd>Hue/Saturation</kbd>, choose <kbd>Colorize</kbd>.

[image]